# How can I change RGB values of pcl::PointXYZRGBA?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

I have a point of the type  `pcl::PointXYZRGBA`. How can I assign/change its rgb values?

For changing xyz coordinates, I can simply do `point.x = some_value`.

Comment: The class `Point` does not seems to exist in the Pcl doc... I can only find [pcl::PointXYZRGBA](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b_a.html).

Comment: @Synxis : You are right. I am referring to an instance named 'point' of the class  pcl::PointXYZRGBA .

Comment: Can't you use `getRGBEigen3i()`, or `point.r` (and same for `g`and `b`) ?

Comment: @Synxis : with getRGBEigen3i(), I cannot replace them. About using point.r, I found a thread on pcl-users forum that said otherwise.

Comment: i've replaced one of your tags, the correct one is point-cloud-library

Answer (score 10):

Or just use

```
point.r = 255;
point.b = 0;
point.g = 0;
point.a = 255;
```

Comment: This should be the corrected answer. Simple and clear.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pcl::PointXYZRGB` instead of `pcl::PointXYZRGBA`. I think they both do the same. And then to color a point red (255,0,0), you can do:

```
pcl::PointXYZRGB point = pcl::PointXYZRGB(255, 0, 0);
```

And the xyz-coordinates can then be assigned respectively:

```
point.x = x;
point.y = y;
point.z = z;
```

**EDIT:** Or if you have to stick with `pcl::PointXYZRGBA`, you can do

```
pcl::PointXYZRGBA point;
uint8_t r = 255;
uint8_t g = 0;
uint8_t b = 0;
int32_t rgb = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b; 
point.rgba = *(float *)(&rgb); // makes the point red
```

Comment: Your second part is wrong - `.rgba` is a `uint32_t`