# converting pcloudXYZ to pcloudXYZRGB using pcl 1.6

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am new to PCL and also to C++. I need to convert a point cloud of XYZ type to a point cloud of XYZRGB type and vice versa, using PCL 1.6. I tried 'pcl::copyPointCloud(cloud, cloudRGB);' but VS2010 says: "no instance of overloaded function 'pcl::copyPointCloud' matches the argument list". I don't know what exactly it means, so how could I solve it? In [documentation](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.6.0/group__common.html#ga4e98fb8923a6d8c4dab35ff96c7b1dd6) I find that function needs three variables, but I don't know what is the second, and how to find it. Other examples don't use the second one, but I don't know if they use PCL 1.6.

Thank you very much for your helps

Answer (score 1):

to convert one data type to another in pcl you can u this function:

```
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> input;
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud;
  pcl::copyPointCloud(input,cloud);
```

But here the data's input should be in the form of xyz+rgb format, than only it is possible. which is read as input=camera/registered_image/points

Answer (score 0):

Fill up the rgb data with 0 :D, you can't just simply convert the two things, because you don't have any rgb data.

[Look here for the official documentation and example](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/structpcl_1_1_point_x_y_z_r_g_b.html)

Comment: Ok, but when could I use the function 'pcl::copyPointCloud(cloud, cloudRGB);'? It is only to pass from pointcloud RGB to simple pointcloud and so losing color information? Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: I don't think you can do it, because the type is not the same. Try it if it works then you just loose the color.

Comment: Look here : [possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999331/how-can-i-change-rgb-values-of-pclpointxyzrgba)

Comment: I just do [this modification](http://justpaste.it/dd1t), that is use of the asterisk and VS2010 doesn't detect error. Now I have other errors in other parts of the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322535/pclmovingleastsquares-doesnt-work) to solve before knowing that it works.